# getaddrinfo() returns loopback address

Tags: c, sockets

My target machine for some socket communication application in a LAN has `192.168.98.91` for IPv4.

When I try to resolve IPaddress with getaddrinfo() it returns `127.0.0.1`

How can I get `192.168.98.91`?

I've set `192.168.98.91` for `myhost` in `/etc/hosts`file and ping I did to `myhost` showed `192.168.98.91` as IP address.

My machine is CentOS6.4.

This is setting of /etc/hosts.

```
192.168.98.91   myhost
127.0.0.1   myhost localhost.localdomain
```

This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int
main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int sock;
    struct addrinfo hints,*res;
    int n;
    int err;
    if(argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage : %s dst \n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    } 
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; 
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    err = getaddrinfo(argv[1],"12345",&hints,&res);
    if(err != 0){
        perror("getaddrinfo");
        printf("getaddrinfo %s\n",strerror(errno));
        printf("getaddrinfo : %s \n",gai_strerror(err));
        return 1;
    }

    sock = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,0);
    if(sock < 0){
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }
    {
        const char *ipverstr;
        switch (res->ai_family){
            case AF_INET:
                ipverstr = "IPv4";
                break;
            case AF_INET6:
                ipverstr = "IPv6";
                break;
            default:
                ipverstr = "unknown";
                break;            
        }
        printf("ipverstr = %s\n ",ipverstr);            
    }
    n = sendto(sock,"HELLO",5,0,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen);
    //n = sendto(sock,"HELLO", 5, 0,(struct sockaddr *)addr, sizeof(addr));
    if(n<1){
        perror("sendto");
        {

        }
        return 1;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in *addr;
    addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr; 
    printf("inet_ntoa(in_addr)sin = %s\n",inet_ntoa((struct in_addr)addr->sin_addr));

    printf("############ finish !! #######\n");
    close(sock);
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code showing how `getaddrinfo()` actually is used seems to be essential to understand what's wrong with it. Dare showing it to us ...! ;-)

Comment: Have you walked the linked list of addresses returned by getaddrinfo?

Comment: Did you go through the list? getaddrinfo() might give you more than one address.

Comment: The sympthoms described sound quiet weired, as a loopback address should only pop up when asking for `localhost`, `lo` or such. So I propose you also show us the machine's `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hosts.conf` files.

Comment: I edited to add my code and setting of hosts.I don't use hosts.conf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd follow the chain of results returned by `getaddrinfo()` using the `ai_next` member of `struct addrinfo` you'd also get `192.168.98.91` for `myhost`.

Here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html you find a full example also showing how to do this:

From the link above:

```
       ...
       s = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &hints, &result);
       if (s != 0) {
           fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       /* getaddrinfo() returns a list of address structures.
          Try each address until we successfully bind(2).
          If socket(2) (or bind(2)) fails, we (close the socket
          and) try the next address. */

       for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
          /* Do something with rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, ... */
       }
       ...
```

---

Removing `myhost` from this line in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   myhost localhost.localdomain
```

would result in `127.0.0.1` not being  returned by `getaddrinfo()` anymore when asking it for `myhost`.

Comment: Now I can see `192.168.98.91`.